# How to make 1 vertical line visible in table

Tags: html

Any tips how to make only 1 vertical line visible in a table? Example: I have a 2 row, 2 column table and I only want the middle vertical line to be visible. None of the outside borders need to be visible.

Answer (score 4):

Set your css like

```
table {
    border: none;
    border-spacing: 0;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
table tr td:nth-child(2) {
    border-left: 1px solid red;
}
```

Comment: This will unfortunately leave a break in the "line" between rows however.

Comment: Updated. Now the cellspacing is off.